# how to change a password of an authenticated user in laravel

Tags: laravel

How can i change password of an unauthenticated user, i have an admin panel, and i want the admin to have the ability to change password of other staff registered on the platform. So basically the admin registers the staff with an email and password. So i want a functionality where by the admin can change any of the staff password.

My problem is am getting invalid current password even after inputting the correct current password, while trying to change a staff password.

This is the code below

//ChangeStaffPassword.blade.php

```
<!-- Change password Success or Error Message-->
 @if(Session::has('success'))
            <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible">
            <button type="button" class='close' data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true"></button>
            <center><h4 style="..."><i class="icon fa fa-ban"></i>  {!! Session('success') !!} </h4></center>
            </div>
     @endif
  
                @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
        <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible">
        <button type="button" class='close' data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true"></button>
        <center><h4 style="..."><i class="icon fa fa-ban"></i> Invalid Current Password! </h4></center>
        </div>
          @endforeach 


      $id = 7
 <form name="myform" role="form" method="post" action="{{ route('change-password.update', $id) }}" onsubmit="return validateform()">
            @csrf
    
              <div class="form-group row text-left text-warning">
                <div class="col-sm-3" style="padding-top: 5px;">
                 <b>Enter Current Password:</b>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-9">
                  <input class="form-control" type="password" placeholder="Enter Current Password" name="old_pass" required>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group row text-left text-warning">
                <div class="col-sm-3" style="padding-top: 5px;">
                 <b>Enter New Password:</b>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-9">
                  <input class="form-control" type="password" placeholder="Enter New Password" name="new_pass" required>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group row text-left text-warning">
                <div class="col-sm-3" style="padding-top: 5px;">
                 <b>Re-Enter New Password:</b>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-9">
                  <input class="form-control" type="password" placeholder="Re-Enter New Password" name="confirm_pass" required>
                </div>
              </div>
              
              <hr>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning btn-block"><i 
             class="fa fa-edit fa-fw"></i>Proceed to Change Password</button>    
              </form>
```

//Route

```
Route::post('/change-password/{user}', [App\Http\Controllers\AdminController::class, 'update'])
    ->name('change-password.update');
```

//AdminController

```
public function update(Request $request, Staff $user)
{

   $validate = $request->validate([
        'old_pass' => ['required', new MatchStaffOldPassword($user)],
        'new_pass' => ['required', 'confirmed'],
    ]);

    $user->password = Hash::make($request->new_pass);
    $user->save();

    return redirect(route('/ChangeStaffPassword'))->with('success', 'Password updated');
}
```

//MatchStaffOldPassword

```
    <?php

namespace App\Rules;
use  App\Models\Staff;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Rule;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;

class MatchStaffOldPassword implements Rule
{

    private $user;
    /**
     * Create a new rule instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(Staff $user)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
    }

    /**
     * Determine if the validation rule passes.
     *
     * @param  string  $attribute
     * @param  mixed  $value
     * @return bool
     */
    public function passes($attribute, $value)
    {
        return Hash::check($value, $this->user->password);
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation error message.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function message()
    {
        return 'The :attribute must match the old password';
    }
}
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Is your `admin` going to know the `old password` of your other `staff` user?

Comment: Yes, because it's the admin that will add the staff details to the database

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your `admin` will know the `old` password for the given `staff` user, lets build a basic form to capture the `old_pass`, `new_pass` and a `confirmation` for `new_pass`.

**Note: I am using `User` as I am too lazy to create a `Staff` model, so just replace instances of `User` with `Staff` if you have such a concept**

```
<form action="{{ route('change-password.update', $user->id) }}" method="post">
    @csrf

    <div>
        <label for="old_pass">{{ __("Old Password") }}</label>
        <input type="password" id="old_pass" name="old_pass">
        @error("old_pass")
        <span>{{ $message }}</span>
        @enderror
    </div>

    <div>
        <label for="new_pass">{{ __("Password") }}</label>
        <input type="password" id="new_pass" name="new_pass">
        @error("new_pass")
        <span>{{ $message }}</span>
        @enderror
    </div>

    <div>
        <label for="new_pass_confirmation">{{ __("Confirm Password") }}</label>
        <input type="password" id="new_pass_confirmation" name="new_pass_confirmation">
        @error("new_pass_confirmation")
        <span>{{ $message }}</span>
        @enderror
    </div>

    <div>
        <button class="submit">{{ __("Update") }}</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Define a `route` in the `web.php` file to process your request, for this example mine looks as follows:

```
Route::post('/change-password/{user}', [ChangeStaffPasswordController::class, 'update'])
    ->name('change-password.update');
```

Notice the `name` of the `route` and the action of the form match. The `route` helper in the form action also requires the `id` of the `staff` user you want to update. This could be passed along in your url for example (`/change-password/1/edit`).

To process the password update request, you want to check the old password against the `staff` user provided. You can't use `auth()->user()` as that checks the currently logged in user.

I created a specific controller for processing the password change request. Whilst not essential it allows you to stick to just the 7 restful controller actions.

```
class ChangeStaffPasswordController extends Controller
{
    public function update(Request $request, User $user)
    {
        $validate = $request->validate([
            'old_pass' => ['required', new MatchStaffOldPassword($user)],
            'new_pass' => ['required', 'confirmed'],
        ]);

        $user->password = Hash::make($request->new_pass);
        $user->save();

        return redirect(route('/some-route'))->with('success', 'Password updated');
    }
}
```

To compare the provided `old_pass` with the `staff` password, I created a new validation rule `MatchStaffOldPassword`. This works in a very similar manner to your `MatchOldPassword` rule but it accepts a `User` as a parameter.

```
class MatchStaffOldPassword implements Rule
{
    private $user;

    /**
     * Create a new rule instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(User $user)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
    }

    /**
     * Determine if the validation rule passes.
     *
     * @param  string  $attribute
     * @param  mixed  $value
     * @return bool
     */
    public function passes($attribute, $value)
    {
        return Hash::check($value, $this->user->password);
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation error message.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function message()
    {
        return 'The :attribute must match the old password';
    }
}
```

All this does is compare the provided `old_pass` (which is the `$value` parameter in the `passes` function) against the password stored in the database for the provided `$user`. Alternatively, you could just alter your existing rule if you want.

Comment: Thank you for your help, but am getting invalid current password while trying to change the staff password. Kindly go through my question again, i have updated it, with a new code.

Comment: @Otis You don't appear to have a `$user` property in your `MatchOldStaffPassword` rule.

Comment: i don't get you, is the property $user not passed from the AdminController to the MatchOldStaffPassword here ------ 'old_pass' => ['required', new MatchStaffOldPassword($user)], Or can you guide me more

Comment: @Otis The `User` is passed as a parameter to the rule exactly as you've outlined, however, in your actual rule (the class `MatchOldStaffPassword`) you've not defined a property on the class to hold the `User`. Compare my example with yours.

Comment: Okay, i get what you are trying to say, I defined a property private $user to hold the Staff, i mistakenly cut it out when pasting the code here. I have updated the rule to exactly how it is in my code giving me invalid current password

Comment: Are you sure the password you're providing as `old_pass` is the correct password for the `Staff` you're trying to update?